# Sending lotus notes mail using Windows command line

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to send email using lotus notes through batch file
Same question with this link

superuser.com/questions/759191/sending-an-email-with-lotus-notes-using-windows-command-line

I already have this code from the link above

C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes>notes mailto:email@example.com?subject=My email^&body=some text^&attach=c:\autoexec.bat

But it only creates new message add recipient,subject,body and attachment. I need to hit the send button for email to be sent. What should I add so it will automatically send the mail without me pressing send button

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The link you referenced, has another link to download the command line "add-on":  https://github.com/OpenNTF/CommandLineEmailClient

**Requirements**

- IBM Notes, v8 or later, client must be installed locally.
- IBM Domino as mail server.
- 32-bit Java 1.7 or later.
- PATH environment variable must include path to Java-executable.

CLENotes is tested with Windows but Linux and Mac should work too.

According to the [OpenNTF documentation](https://github.com/OpenNTF/CommandLineEmailClient/blob/master/src/files/samplecommands.md), the command line example is:

```
clenotes.cmd send --to=recipient@org.org --subject="Status change: Tracking ID 12345" --body="Your order ID 12345. Status changed to: COMPLETE." --attach=orderReceipt.pdf
```